# JS array isn't being accessed properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got an array holding various notifications, which includes their individual title and description. I want to access a certain notification by its title, but I'm not seeming to be able to find a match in the array, even though there should be.

```
NotificationMenu = function()
{
   var NotificationItems = new Array();

   this.Application = function(title, description, functionName)
   {
       this.mTitle = title;
       this.mDescription = description;
       this.mFunction = functionName;
       this.mIsActive = true;
   }

   this.registerNotification = function(title, description, functionName)
   {
       NotificationItems.push(new this.Application(title, description, functionName));
   }

   this.activateNotification = function(title)
   {
       console.log("-NotificationMenu: Activating notification " + title);

       // Check through the list of notifications for the one called to be shown
       for(var i = 0; i < NotificationItems.length; ++i)
       {
           if (NotificationItems[i].mName === title)
           {
               // This is never getting called
               console.log("-NotificationMenu: Successful entry");
           }
       }
   }
}
```

What is wrong with the way I'm accessing my array so that it cannot match two titles? In particular the line `if(NotificationItems[i].mName === title)` is not ever returning `true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no `mName` defined in the `Application()` constructor. Perhaps you mean to use `mTitle`:

```
if (NotificationItems[i].mTitle === title)
```

Comment: *bonks head* Doing! That's exactly it, gosh, thanks! It's the small things that sometimes needs new eyes to catch